# bq load failed with connection error, still it uploaded data

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a script to upload JSON newline delimited data using `bq`. `bq` failed saying `BigQuery error in load operation: Connection error. Please try again.`. Our script retried 5 times till it succeeded. Unfortunately data was uploaded 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

This one from Jordan:

> There is a little-known flag to prevent double-uploads in the bq tool
>   (if you are using that for import). If you use "--fingerprint_job_id"
>   it will use a job id that is based on a hash of the file names you are
>   loading, and so will fail with an 'already exists' error if you try to
>   run it a second time.

If you are not using the bq tool, you can set a manual job id - this to prevent the same job running twice like in this case.

If you added the same data 5 times to the same table, and you want to go back to the table you had before, table decorators can help. You can go back to any state in the last 7 days. See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators.